# PHP websocket private message

Tags: websocket

I'm desperate :(

A week ago I found this wonderful tutorial for WebSockets in PHP
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Everything is working fine but I want, that only 2 user chat with each other (private chat). To declare which users will chat with each other I want to use their IDs from my existing site.

The chat should be an add-on for an existing community.

If you have any idea how to do this, I'll be very thankful!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You will have to implement some kind of *rooms* logic within the main loop of the file `server.php`. Where only two users can chat with each other in the same room. It is not that simple however because You will have to add some kind of conditions for users to join a room. Maybe room is password ? Maybe a room has some unique ID or URL... If room is already full You wont let another users to join it.  The list of rooms will be probably dynamically generated in the `server.php` file, so You can easily track what users are in what room.

Comment: i can do that for you, but I'll charge for that.